# WPF - Retrieve (Select OR Download) Image from Mysql Database in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, image

I am able to download (retrieve) image from Mysql Database in WPF in C# by this piece of code.
This code i have copy from this https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25096053/Retrieve-images-in-C-WPF-Application-from-SQL-Server-Database.html
Website.
But i don't know how this code work line by line. If anyone who have knowledge about this please help.

Code is here.

```
string query = "SELECT image_data from image_table WHERE image_id=22";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Byte[] bindata = (Byte[])dataReader["image_data"];
                MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
                strm.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);
                strm.Position = 0;
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
                download.Source = bi; 
            }
```

Comment: Please someone explain this code to me. Thank You

Comment: Use .NET API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.7.2 to look up APIs you're not familiar with, then ask specific questions about specific parts that you still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to retrieve image from database in wpf in c# with this code. The only problem with this code is it retrieve only one image ata a time. Before using this code add System.Drawing.Imaging. library in your code.

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                    System.Drawing.Image img;
                    MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
                    strm.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);
                    strm.Position = 0;
                    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);
                    bi.BeginInit();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    bi.StreamSource = ms; 
                    bi.EndInit();
```